# SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' always is running

Tags: mysql

I'm using wordpress on a VPS
cpu 20 core
ram 20

but my cpu and  VIRT always is high!

[image]

I checking mysql database, I found out this query is always running:

```
SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'
```

[image]

my total rows of `wp_options`:

```
1470
```

Comment: Yes that’s normal. WordPress needs to load its settings on every request. The number of results seems high but it’s impossible to say why or what the problem is with the information provided though.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.